# Need more examples on how to use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel

Tags: perl, excel, csv, spreadsheet, cpan

I have been using the [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel/) to list the contents of spreadsheet. I've seen several examples on how to dump the entire spreadsheet.   I really would like to see how to use this script more selectively.

The example below from IBM basically dumps the content of all cells that have data.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

my $oExcel = new Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;

die "You must provide a filename to $0 to be parsed as an Excel file" unless @ARGV;

my $oBook = $oExcel->Parse($ARGV[0]);
my($iR, $iC, $oWkS, $oWkC);
print "FILE  :", $oBook->{File} , "\n";
print "COUNT :", $oBook->{SheetCount} , "\n";

print "AUTHOR:", $oBook->{Author} , "\n"
 if defined $oBook->{Author};

for(my $iSheet=0; $iSheet < $oBook->{SheetCount} ; $iSheet++)
{
 $oWkS = $oBook->{Worksheet}[$iSheet];
 print "--------- SHEET:", $oWkS->{Name}, "\n";
 for(my $iR = $oWkS->{MinRow} ;
     defined $oWkS->{MaxRow} && $iR <= $oWkS->{MaxRow} ;
     $iR++)
 {
  for(my $iC = $oWkS->{MinCol} ;
      defined $oWkS->{MaxCol} && $iC <= $oWkS->{MaxCol} ;
      $iC++)
  {
   $oWkC = $oWkS->{Cells}[$iR][$iC];
   print "( $iR , $iC ) =>", $oWkC->Value, "\n" if($oWkC);
  }
 }
}
```

Can someone give me an example of how I can specify some action to take for a certain column for every row?

For example, I have a spreadsheet with 7 columns and n rows.  I want to reformat the data in each of the columns in a certain way. Perhaps I want take column 6 for every row and append some text to the end of the string stored in the cell.  How would that be set up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To modify an Excel file, the [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser) module is very useful. It allows you to read a file, make modifications, and then write the altered content to a new file. Here's a simple example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser;

my $excel_file_name = $ARGV[0];
my $parser          = Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser->new();
my $workbook_orig   = $parser->Parse($excel_file_name);

# We will edit column 7 of the first worksheet.
my $worksheet = $workbook_orig->worksheet(0);
my $EDIT_COL = 6;

my ($row_min, $row_max) = $worksheet->row_range();
for my $r ($row_min .. $row_max){
    my $cell = $worksheet->get_cell($r, $EDIT_COL);
    unless (defined $cell){
        next; # Modify as needed to handle blank cells.
    }
    my $val = $cell->value . '_append_text';
    $worksheet->AddCell( $r, $EDIT_COL, $val, $cell->{FormatNo} );
}

# You can save the modifications to the same file, but when
# you are learning, it's safer to write to a different file.
$excel_file_name =~ s/\.xls$/_new.xls/;
$workbook_orig->SaveAs($excel_file_name);
```

For many other examples, see the excellent documentation:

- [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel::SaveParser)
- [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::WriteExcel)
- [Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Examples](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::WriteExcel::Examples)
- [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Spreadsheet::ParseExcel)

Comment: I'm the maintainer of Spreadsheet::ParseExcel and I think that this is a nice, clear example. ++

Comment: Wow, fantastic example. Thanks very much!  And thanks all of your contributions and for such awesome tools!

Comment: I got the following:  Can't call method "value" on an undefined value at ./excel-test-new line 19.

Comment: @XL After you get `$cell` from the `get_cell` method, you often need to check whether it is defined. If not, it means the cell in the spreadsheet was blank. I edited my answer to illustrate the idea.

Answer (score 2):

To reformat the data in each of the columns in a certain way, you can use the combination of `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel` and `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` modules like

Create a new excel by `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` module and add worksheet in it.Then Parse the existing Excel and write the content into new excel with formating.

Here is a sample example:

```
use strict;
use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel;
use Spreadsheet::WriteExcel;

die "You must provide a filename to $0 to be parsed as an Excel file" unless @ARGV;

my $oBook = $oExcel->Parse($ARGV[0]);
my($iR, $iC, $oWkS, $oWkC);
my $workbook  = Spreadsheet::WriteExcel->new('/root/Desktop/test_simple.xls');
my $worksheet = $workbook->add_worksheet();
$worksheet->set_column('A:A', 50);
my $format = $workbook->add_format();
            $format->set_size(10);
            $format->set_bold();
            $format->set_color('black');
            $format->set_font('Verdana');
            $format->set_text_wrap();
for(my $iSheet=0; $iSheet < $oBook->{SheetCount} ; $iSheet++)
        {
                    $oWkS = $oBook->{Worksheet}[$iSheet];
            for(my $iR = $oWkS->{MinRow} ;defined $oWkS->{MaxRow} && $iR <= $oWkS->{MaxRow} ;$iR++)
            {
                for(my $iC = $oWkS->{MinCol} ;defined $oWkS->{MaxCol} && $iC <= $oWkS->{MaxCol} ;$iC++)
                {
                   $oWkC = $oWkS->{Cells}[$iR][$iC];
                   $worksheet->write($iR , $iC,  $oWkC->Value, $format) if($oWkC); #writing a new excel from existing excel
                }
            }
        }
```

After writing a new excel from the existing excel, you can use API's of `Spreadsheet::WriteExcel` to append data in it.It will solve problems like

1. First it will retain your existing Excel file.
2. you can do formating into new excel file without modifying the original Excel File.

Comment: Do you know how we can handle the merge cells here ?