# How to read properties of an Excel file/workbook (author, title etc) with Perl

Tags: excel, perl

How can I read the properties of an Excel file, for example, author, title, subject, etc. using the perl module?

I wanted to use a `Spreadsheet::ParseExcel`, however, did not find the right method.
In `Excel::Writer::XLSX` has a `set_properties()` method for creating document properties.
Is there an analogue for reading the properties of an Excel document?

Comment: "did not find the right method": where did you look?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Need more examples on how to use Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3217204/need-more-examples-on-how-to-use-spreadsheetparseexcel)

Comment: "_See the Spreadsheet::XLSX module instead_"  -- indeed, you need that module to open an XSLX file ... but then practically all functionality is from the one you use.  And I just can't see anything that would directly return those properties.  Perhaps some roundabout way?

Comment: @ScottHunter "_Does this answer your question?_"  No, it doesn't. Good idea, but it turns out this is a very good question, without any posted approach that I can find.  I was curious and looked through docs and indeed can't find how to do it.  I edited the title to show upfront what the question actually is -- about an Excel document _properties_, not just how to read a file.

Comment: @zdim: The linked question extracts the File(name?), SheetCount & Author properties.

Comment: Simply put, I need to save a specific version number in an Excel document. The easiest way is to use document properties. Maybe there is another way?

Comment: @ScottHunter "_The linked question extracts the File(name?), SheetCount & Author properties._"  -- filename and sheet-count _can_ indeed be obtained, as there are methods for them.  But I get nothing for `$wb->{Author}` (for any properties I wrote for my example Excel file), nor are they there when I dump the whole object (that contains the parsed file).  Also, that'd be a bad hack, to directly read data -- if there is no method for it then consider it unavailable.  Finally, the question's code prints that `if defined` ... we don't whether they're merely guessing?

Comment: @AlexGudkoff  "_Simply put, I need to save a specific version number in an Excel document. The easiest way is to use document properties. Maybe there is another way?_ -- I was curious and wrote a document with various properties (added through multiple means), and "dump"-ed the whole object after parsing the file -- and can't find those properties in the dump.  Perhaps Perl's libraries just can't extract them... Maybe use a comment, or keep it in the filename (not good solutions really but I don't see how to do it).  Perhaps shoot an email to the module's author?  They would know.

Comment: @AlexGudkoff Final, option that I can see: see [module's source](https://metacpan.org/dist/Spreadsheet-ParseXLSX/source/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseXLSX.pm) to see how they do it, and do it yourself to extract those properties.  It looks like they just need `Archive::Zip` (? -- I'd expect more).  But I'd say send a nice email and ask

Comment: @AlexGudkoff Then I'd suggest to post an answer with what you find, since this is a big hole in documented knowledge; it'd be nice to know how to use properties.  (Unless somebody comes along and post it!)

Comment: (by "module's author" I mean module's maintainer)